# bootstrap - unwanted padding on top of carousel-inner

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap and using a carousel below two navbars.

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xneym8zq/

The problem is that there is a gap between the top of the carousel and the carousel-inner. I can see that the carousel is touching the navbar due to the carousel-control shadow but what I don't get is why is there a gap between the top and the image.

I've tried

```
.carousel-inner .item img {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

It works but what I want to know is why is there a gap? and which element is causing it? Is there some default css in bootstrap.css that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to understand first the bootstrap by applying their example not diving into a duplicate from another work.

Comment: the problem is not the carousel, it is the header, if you give a height of 95 and overflow hidden to the header u'll see

Comment: oka the height and overflow hiddern worked. but can you please tell me why it worked? I still can't wrap my head around it.